# Can I use Windows DLL files on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, dll

I am working in C++ programming using Linux based qt.

I want to import a C based .dll file into my C++ project. Is this possible?

Comment: `.dll` file format won't work on linux.

Comment: You need shared library ( *.so) on Linux.  AFAIK, DLL file format is completely different it won't work on Linux